# Cloud build export cloud sql add date in filename

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Here is my pipeline :

```
 steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['sql', 'export', 'sql', $_DB_INSTANCE_NAME, gs://$_BUCKET_NAME/$_FILENAME.sql, '--database=$_DB_DATABASE']

 options:
  dynamic_substitutions: true
  substitution_option: 'ALLOW_LOOSE'
 timeout: 3600s
```

I declared my variable $_FILENAME inside cloud build pipline and I set this value `Cloud_Export_$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`

But I got this error : `Compilation failed: [_FILENAME -> Cloud_Export_$(date +%Y-%m-%d)]: generic::invalid_argument: unable to fetch payload for date +%Y-%m-%d`

So I tried to remove `$()` to my $_FILENAME = `Cloud_Export_date +%Y-%m-%d`

```
Exporting Cloud SQL instance...
...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.sql.export.sql) [ERROR_RDBMS] GCS URI "gs://export_bdd/Cloud_Export_date +%Y-%m-%d.sql" is empty or invalid
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

How can I do to add the current date to my filename ?

**Edit**

I tried to create another variable `_CURRENT_DATE` with value `date +%Y-%m-%d`. Then I changed my `$_FILENAME` variable to `Cloud_Export_${_CURRENT_DATE}`

Now I don't have any errors but the date is empty the filename is `Cloud_Export_.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution I removed the `$_FILENAME` variable then I'm using sh entrypoint and I added double `$` to the date function `$$(date +%Y-%m-%d)` and it works :

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'sh'
    args: ['-c', 'gcloud sql export sql $_DB_INSTANCE gs://$_BUCKET_NAME/filename_$$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql --database=$_DB_NAME']
```